# Restlet adding a custom decoder

Tags: java, restlet

Im requiring lz4 decompression support on a Restlet service, but am unsure how to achieve this.  Is there some way I can register a custom input stream with a custom Content Encoding to ensure that my request.getEntity.getStream will be appropriately decoded?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting the request entity with a wrapper representation

```
request.setEntity(new Lz4DecodedRepresentation(request.getEntity()))
```

where Lz4DecodedReprentation over-road getStream()